# Is possible to use Relay in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql, relay

I have express server and I need load some data from GraphQL server e.g. data for routes, or data for sitemap etc. Is it possible to do with Relay ? I know that Apollo client can be used in backend (nodejs) too, so my question is - is the same possible with Relay ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using fetch on server side.